# Conversion Error when passing arguments to lambda comparator

Tags: c++

I have a sorted vector of structures and I am trying to find the index of element that has the queried value in its member attribute. For this I am trying to use lower_bound, but I am having problems with the comparator lambda function. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Student
{
    int id;
};

std::vector<Student> Students;

int main()
{
    Student Ann = {1};
    Student Bob = {3};
    Student Alice = {4};
    Students = {Ann, Bob, Alice};
    int id_query = 3;
    auto index_ptr = std::lower_bound(Students.begin(), Students.end(), id_query, [](const int a, const Student s) -> bool {return a < s.id;});
}
```

g++ with std=17 gives me the following

```
Starting build...
/bin/g++ -g /home/aram/dev/cpp/coverages/stack_overflow.cpp -std=c++17 -o /home/aram/dev/cpp/coverages/stack_overflow
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/aram/dev/cpp/coverages/stack_overflow.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >; _Value = const int; _Compare = main()::<lambda(int, Student)>]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:979:14:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__lower_bound(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >; _Tp = int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<main()::<lambda(int, Student)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:2032:32:   required from ‘_FIter std::lower_bound(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >; _Tp = int; _Compare = main()::<lambda(int, Student)>]’
/home/aram/dev/cpp/coverages/stack_overflow.cpp:21:142:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: error: no match for call to ‘(main()::<lambda(int, Student)>) (Student&, const int&)’
  177 |  { return bool(_M_comp(*__it, __val)); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: note: candidate: ‘bool (*)(int, Student)’ <conversion>
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 3 provided
/home/aram/dev/cpp/coverages/stack_overflow.cpp:21:83: note: candidate: ‘main()::<lambda(int, Student)>’
   21 |     auto index_ptr = std::lower_bound(Students.begin(), Students.end(), id_query, [](const int a, const Student s) -> bool {return a < s.id;});
      |                                                                                   ^
/home/aram/dev/cpp/coverages/stack_overflow.cpp:21:83: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Student’ to ‘int’

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparator of [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) is supposed to take the object dereferenced from the iterator, i.e. the element as the 1st parameter, the value to be compared as the 2nd parameter.

> The type `Type1` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type1`. The type `Type2` must be such that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to `Type2`.​

You need to change the order of the parameters, e.g.

```
auto index_ptr = std::lower_bound(Students.begin(), Students.end(), id_query, [](const Student s, const int a) -> bool {return s.id < a;});
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CqPO39Pu2LPjg5Ba)

Comment: It does make sense when you put it this way, ty!